# How to add join query in method crudbooster in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, crudbooster

I have method **code** :

```
public function getAddProfil($id)
{
    //Create an Auth
    if (!CRUDBooster::isCreate() && $this->global_privilege==FALSE || $this->button_add==FALSE) {    
        CRUDBooster::redirect(CRUDBooster::adminPath(),trans("crudbooster.denied_access"));
    }

    $data = [];
    $data['page_title'] = 'Add Data Profil';
    $data['result'] = DB::table('cms_users')->orderby('id','desc')->where('id','=',$id)->get();

    //Please use cbView method instead view method from laravel
    $this->cbView('profil_add',$data);
}
```

any **suggest** how to add join in :

```
$data['result'] = DB::table('cms_users')->orderby('id','desc')->where('id','=',$id)->get();
```

I have tried adding **join** :

```
$data['result'] = DB::table('cms_users')->join('profil')->orderby('id','desc')->where('id','=',$id)->get();
```

and then I got **error** in the crudbooster.

Comment: Show you are getting the error and also share the db structure

Comment: blob:https://stackoverflow.com/7a061d29-0023-4729-aa64-606b527c3a9f 
i have 3 table : cms_users have fk from profil and profil have fk from job

Comment: Hey share the db structure with its column name like primary and foreign key in your question.

Comment: have you done using relation?instead of join both of the table actually connected through relationship. use `with('profile')` . more info can be found here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Comment: sama-sama @TegarPrakoso kalau ada masalah langsung aja nanya aku aku bantuin.

Comment: @Mace i wanna ask you i have been try other source code but this one can get the data, but cant get the relationship that i want. here the source code :  `$data['result'] = DB::table('cms_users')->orderby('id','desc')->where('id','=',$id)->get();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found the answer, and use this source code and it's work :

```
$data['result'] = DB::table('cms_users')
              ->join('profil', 'cms_users.profil_id', '=', 'profil.id')
              ->join('jabatan', 'profil.jabatan_id', '=', 'jabatan.id')
              ->join('ruang', 'profil.ruang_id', '=', 'ruang.id')
              ->join('pangkat', 'profil.pangkat_id', '=', 'pangkat.id')
              ->orderby('cms_users.id','desc')
              ->where('cms_users.id', $id)
              ->get();
```

thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

**Try to do this:**

```
$data['result'] = DB::table('cms_users')->join('profil', 'cms_users.profil_id', '=', 'profil.id')->orderby('cms_users.id','desc')->where('cms_users.id', $id)->get();
```

I hope it would helpful.

Comment: sorry, okay i'll try your suggest. thank you for fast respon @Inzamam Idrees

Comment: i've done tried your suggestion but the **array** is not get the data `Collection {#612 ▼
  #items: []
}`

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel query builder ->Join() requires 4 parameters,see example below:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
            ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
            ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
            ->get();
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Please help me understand why this answer is marked not useful.

Comment: i'll try your suggest, in the array is null. and then i try this code `$data['result'] = DB::table('cms_users')->orderby('id','desc')->where('id','=',$id)->get();` i got the data, but the relastionship it's not work